# "Instance Point on Faces" is not carrying over the proper textures in blender geo-nodes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, shaders, geometry-nodes, instances

I'm using geometry nodes in blender 3.41 and instancing a bunch of object on a plane to create a really complex scene. This is a technique learned from Max Hay on YouTube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ln1IpYnufxc

The pillar objects are textures as stand alone assets but once places with the " distribute points on faces" node they lose their texture and look like clay. The only solution I have found is to change the texture coordinate node to "camera" but it breaks my animation. What am I doing wrong?

It should also be noted that i'm using the addon "1 click damage" so my pillars require 2 textures to look right.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Easiest thing to do is:

**Don't** *realize instances*.

#### If you do want to *realize instances* and still have the textures work; all you have to do is:

use an *attribute* node (in the shader editor) and as the name put the name of the uv map your instances has, then use that instead of the *texture coordinate* node.